# Yellow object between δ Ori and η Ori

Tags: star, constellations

Can someone perhaps assist me in identifying the yellow object between δ Ori and η Ori? I took an image of this object, but I can't identify it.

It can be seen on the image below, hosted on the Eagle Creek Obs. site. (http://www.eaglecreekobservatory.org/eco/doubles/images/ori.gif)

It's the orange object on the constellation line between 28 and 34.

[image: Orion Constellation]

Comment: You're going to have a hard time finding an answer to this one.

Comment: You should get yourself a good planetarium app like a stellarium, The SkyX, or Sky Safari

Answer (score 2):

Someone suggested this object to be 31 Ori. After further research, equipped with the name, I confirmed this object to be 31 Ori. Source of confirmation: http://www.astrostudio.org/xhip.php?hip=25737